# Write Conflict Error in Access Resolved Once After Saving Class Module

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form for viewing data in a table, which can open a pop up form to edit the data.

When data is edited in the pop up form, Access throws a write conflict error upon closing that form and returning to the original.

The strange behavior I'm experiencing is that when I make a change to the popup's class module in VBA, even if I immediately undo the change and save, the error will be resolved exactly once.

To be clear:

1. I make a change to the popup's class module in VBA (even a change I immediately undo and re-save)
2. I can open the pop up from my original form, edit records, then close the pop up. No error is thrown on closing the pop up.
3. I then open the pop up and edit records a second time. Then upon closing the pop up a write conflict error is displayed. This continues each subsequent time.
4. I now make a change to the popup's class module (again, even a trivial one), the error is resolved for one edit again, and the process repeats.

Does anybody know why this behavior could be occurring? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the issue centers on if two users, or in this case two bits of code try to edit a record that is already dirty.

If the main form causes the record to become dirty (changed, but not saved), if then you run ANY other code that ALSO changes that data, then you get the conflict.

The simple solution then is to ALWAYS ensure that the the current forms record is safely tucked away and saved before you run + call code that might change that dirty record. And that includes that popup form + class.

So in your code that launches the form/class code? Do this RIGHT BEFORE you launch that 2nd form:

```
If me.Dirty = True then me.dirty = False
```

So, the above will safe write out the dirty record, and now you are free to launch/run any other code that might change that record. And because you run the above? Well, the record is not dirty anymore, and thus you should not see nor receive a write conflict error.

So adding a check to save if dirty before you launch/run that additional code/form will resolve this issue. In fact, as a habit, for just about "any" launching of additional UI forms, it a good idea to safe tuck away and save the current forms record when launching additional UI bits and parts.

Comment: Hello Albert, thank you for your answer. I have tried making sure that the main form's records are saved before opening the pop up (the main form is locked from editing anyway so I am not sure what it thinks I have changed). However the problem still persists, but it strikes me as strange that making any change to the class module temporarily fixes the issue. I was wondering if it could perhaps be due to something stored by VBA which is cleared upon changing the class module, but I don't have enough experience to know if this is possible or what it might be

Comment: Hello again Albert, I've spent all day looking into this and have eventually discovered that the interference was coming from a subform on the pop up form believing it was dirty. I have no idea why altering the class module temporarily fixed this, but it seems to be working now. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer, but do you it would be best for me to delete this question since this was a very specific issue related to my code, and there are other questions which address the issue of saving the records from one form before opening another?

Comment: Not really. the basic advice when launching a form from a main form, or even a sub form row of data? In 99% of cases, you want the one line of if me.dirty = true then me.dirty = false. So, in 9 out of 10 cases, the advice given will solve these types of issues.

Comment: Ok, thank you again for your help, I will leave the question as is